# Pipinstall not working after installing MySQL

Tags: python, terminal, pip

A couple of weeks ago I installed MySQL on my Mac and I set the following path (I'm unsure about the terminology so I apologize for any confusion)

```
echo 'export PATH = /usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Ever since I have been unable to open Jupyter notebook using my terminal and pipinstall no longer works (I keep getting the message "bash: pipinstall: command not found").

My guess is that I changed something when I installed MySQL because when I try

```
echo $PATH
```

I get

```
/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:@PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

I have no idea what any of this means and I am unsure how to change the path back to the python directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Search all the places involving /usr/local/mysql/bin in ~/.bash_profile, and correct them by :

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify what you mean by "correcting them by..." I have no idea what is going on

Comment: Use an editor like `vi` or `nano` to open ~/.bash_profile and search `mysql` and do the correction